# Returning uneven numbers

Tags: javascript, comparison

I have started learning Javascript and is doing some simple exercises. Given an array of numbers, return uneven numbers. I Have used both the "Classical" way of doing it as well as an arrow function. However they are acting a bit weird. This is the arrow function:

```
const answer2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9].filter(value => {
    return value % 2 != 0;
    })
```

It looks alright to me and it seems to work. Then I did the classical one:

```
function filterArrayToOdd(inputArray) {
    let outputArray = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            outputArray.push(inputArray[i]);
        }
    }
    return outputArray;
}
```

This returns an array with all the even numbers! Changing the comparrison from != to == works, but why?!

Comment: You're checking `i`, not `inputArray[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

It would be better if your test array was not in sequence, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], but rather something like, [2, 5, 9, 11, 12, 3].

In sequence, you can produce false positives to this problem, because, as @Pointy is saying, in your second case, you are checking your array index, not the actual value.

```
// instead of
if (i % 2 != 0) {


// do this:
if (inputArray[i] % 2 != 0) {
```